# Can't add loop cut with Ctrl+R

Tags: modeling

When I try to add a loop cut by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> only a dot shows on my object instead of whole loop cut line. What am I doing wrong to cause this problem?

[image]

Comment: https://www.take-a-screenshot.org

Comment: To make a screen shot on blender press Ctrl+F3 and save the image, you can choose to save an image the whole interface or just the active window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens if you are using the Loop Cut on an edge that isn't connected to the rest of the mesh.
[image]

Try selecting that lower edge and moving it down a little. If it is not connected then just delete it. If the edge you select is connected but you see that there was another edge hiding below it then select that edge and move/delete it.

Or you could select everything and from the Tools panel on the left and use the **Remove Doubles** tool.

[image]